# How to get validate result Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

For quick skip the gui code, and go straight to method validate, i dont know, next step to get validate result when login button click. full code in here https://pastecode.io/s/ut3cuq3p

```
class MainWindow: public QWidget 
{
  Q_OBJECT  
  
  public:
    MainWindow(){ ... }
 
  public slots:    
       void validate(QLineEdit* pUserInput)
       {
         QRegularExpression rx("^[^_\\W]+$");
         QValidator* validator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(rx, this);
         pUserInput->setValidator(validator);

         // what property to get the validate result? 
         // i need to pass to QMessageBox

         QMessageBox message;
         message.setText(validateResult);
         message.exec();
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a validator on a `QLineEdit`, you want to look at the value of `pUserInput->hasAcceptableInput()` but you can set it up better.  You only need to assign the validator to your `QLineEdit` when it is created (unless your validation regex is changing every time), then you can use the signals `QLineEdit::editingFinished` and `QLineEdit::inputRejected` to determine whether the user's input was acceptable - see [QLineEdit documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
...
    QValidator* validator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(rx, this);
    pUserInput->setValidator(validator);
    connect(pUserInput, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, this, &MainWindow::validText);
    connect(pUserInput, &QLineEdit::inputRejected, this, &MainWindow::invalidText);
...
}

void MainWindow::validText()
{
    // pUserInput has valid input text
    ...
}

void MainWindow::invalidText()
{
    // pUserInput has invalid input text
    ...
}
```

Comment: are u already look my code in https://pastecode.io/s/ut3cuq3p? if i use your implement, i need to pass pointer to validText or invalid. Validate method trigger when click. i use lambda to achieve this.

Comment: editingFinished  event trigger in the way that i dont want, "Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus". even when lose focus. i need final validate to post to server to check user  or pass. exists. thats why i need click event.  not real time event from QLineEdit.

Comment: can u check this please, https://pastecode.io/s/fks8avtc. why signal, and slot argument not match? I pass same argument. and use it in changeLabel to change label realtime as input type. using textChanged event.

Comment: They don't match because the `QLineEdit::textChanged` signal returns a `const QString&` and your `changeLabel` function is expecting a `QString&` - you cannot pass a const reference to a function that expects a non-const argument

Comment: If, as you said, you don't want to rely on the `editingFinished` and `inputRejected` signals as I suggested earlier, then if you want to just directly check the validation result all you need to do is check the value of `pUserInput->hasAcceptableInput()`

Comment: Okay,  i change it `QString text`. i make it work for textChanged event. but theres weird happens when i use inputRejected event. my program exit. https://pastecode.io/s/bfsx8woh. complete code. I expect when i input char that not  allow, it will ouput to label. but, program exit suddently

Comment: thank you,  i know now the problem why my program exit suddently. label pointer not know pointer input. what i need to do to make compiler more restrict? the compiler just compile even in pointer  still not pass.